# Forge Viewer: SVF2 of DWF 2D view object properties is not accessible by getProperties function nor do they show on the property panel

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

There seems to be a problem with SVF2 conversion of 2D views in DWF/DWFX files which effectively loses object properties.

The problem is specific to DWF 2D views and SVF2, there is no problem with 3D views in the same DWF, using the SVF of the same file also does not exhibit this problem, and rvt files also shows the properties in all 2D/3D SVF/SVF2 combination.

Also tried viewing the files in the ACC docs viewer which uses SVF2 now, and the behavior is the same.